# Proof of Cone's Volume Using Inscribed Disks

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through George Simmons' precalculus text and there's an example where he proves the formula for the volume of a cone using inscribed disks and the formula $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + … n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

I'm having trouble with the initial intuition.  For a cone of height $h$ and base radius $r$, he starts out with "**let $n$ be a given large positive integer. If there are $n-1$ inscribed disks, then each disk has thickness $\frac{h}{n}$**.

I understand the rest of his steps from that point, but I don't understand why there are only $n-1$ disks if each has a thickness of $\frac{h}{n}$.  Wouldn't it be $n$ disks?  For example, if $n=3$, then the thickness of each disk is $\frac{h}{3}$, right?

For what it's worth, I got the same result by substituting $n$ for $n-1$ and reproducing his steps, but I still don't feel like I understand.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th disk would correspond to the point of the cone.  Each disk is made by slicing the cone and then using the smaller side to determine its radius.  For the last disk, this radius is $0$, so it's not really there.